# Gravitational analogue to the hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm not sure what to make of this problem from Griffiths' Intro to QM:

> Suppose the earth made a transition to the next lower level $(n-1)$. How much energy (in joules) would be released? What would the wavelength of the emitted photon photon (or, more likely, graviton) be? (Express your answer in light years-is the remarkable answer a coincidence?)

Well my answer was almost exactly one light year. What's so remarkable about this? I tried looking around but I didn't get much out of it. Is this the wavelength of a graviton? What is so remarkable?

Comment: Yup, there's a perfectly good reason for the wavelength to be a light-year. Have you learned about emission of light in an E&M class?

Comment: Does Griffiths mention Rydberg atoms and their quasi-classical description?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you may find it interesting in this context: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10582/